# How do i fork a Github repo, make a change, then use it in my app?

Tags: git, github

Actually I know how to fork a repo (lets call it "originalModule") and have already made a small JS fix. However the owner of the npm module isnt maintaining it anymore so isn't doing anything with pull requests.

How can I simply take this forked version and then use it in my (react native) app? I want to be sure than if I ever delete the node_modules dir, when I run "yarn" or "npm install" that i dont get the originalModule and instead get the version from my forked Github location.

Comment: Looks like this question has very little to `git` or `github`, it's only one of potentially numerous delivery ways. I'd suggest adding instead relevant tags like `npm` (I am not even confident enough to suggest the concrete ones).

Answer (score 0):

`npm` is able to install a module from git repo: [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies).

If the change is generally enough, you can also consider to send a Pull Request though :)

Comment: thanks, i tried that and the code change i had made on the (forked) repo still wasnt landing in my node_modules folder. i may be wrong on this but i found that i also needed to change the version number in package.json. Then the yarn install worked.